# How to append entry in the same page using angularJS, without using array to store previous entry

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my html file, that get data from controller. Controller get new data every time from API once i press the load button by increasing the offset value.

```
 <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl">
    <div class="row row-gap" ng-repeat="data in data">
        <div  class="media-left media-middle">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="media-object rounded" ng-src="{{data.thumbnail}}">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body" >
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
               <td class="col-md-3"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" aria-hidden="true">Name</span></td>
                <td class="col-md-9">{{data.title}}</td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-md-3"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Place </td>
              <td class="col-md-9"> Star{{data.placeName}} </td>
               </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-3"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> Submitted On </td>
              <td class="col-md-9">{{data.createdOn |date }}</td>
               </tr>
           </table>
             <img ng-src="{{data.author.icon}}";alt="{{data.author.name}}";height=30px; width=30px  >
        </div>
      </div>

      <button  type="button"  ng-click="loadMore(count=count+1)"  class="btn btn-default">load More</button>

     </div>
```

The container code is as follow. I am aware that i am using the same data variable to store the subsequent query result.
I just want that whenever i click on load more button, data get append in the same page without effecting the previous values.

```
 var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myctrl',function ($scope, $http) {

  $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'API?max=10&offset=0&format=json'

     }).then(function (datacontent){
         $scope.data=datacontent.data.model.observationInstanceList;
        console.log(show);
     },function (error){
//console.log(error);
     });

$scope.count=0;
$scope.loadMore=function(value) {
value=value*10;
  $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://API?max=10&offset='+value+'&format=json'

     }).then(function (dataco){
         $scope.data=dataco.data.model.observationInstanceList;

     },function (error){
//console.log(error);
     });
}

});

  I need answer in such a way, the array size doesnot increase much.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, but only works if `dataco.data.model.observationInstanceList` is an array.

```
$scope.data = $scope.data.length ? $scope.data.concat(dataco.data.model.observationInstanceList) : dataco.data.model.observationInstanceList;
```

Change your code as below

```
$scope.count=0;
$scope.loadMore=function(value) {
value=value*10;
  $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://API?max=10&offset='+value+'&format=json'

     }).then(function (dataco){
         $scope.data = $scope.data.length ? $scope.data.concat(dataco.data.model.observationInstanceList) : dataco.data.model.observationInstanceList;

     },function (error){
//console.log(error);
     });
}
```

Comment: But there is a problem, if the number of entry is very large then the size of the array become very large. there is any alternative how to reduce the array size and keep on updating.  Mr_Perfect